# Rapidjson fails to parse nested object

Tags: c++, json, rapidjson, jsonparser

I am trying to parse json objects from a document. I have a million objects so it has to be generic. I am reading my document line by line and parsing with `jObj.Parse(const str)`. I have some objects that contains nested objects like this,

```
{ "jsonObjectName" : { "A" : "1", "B" : "{\"A\":\"1\",\"B\":\"2\"}" } }
```

Parsing this was okay, at least I thought it was but when I tried to get the object with `jObject.GetObect()` assertion fails and jObject type returns as 0 (kNullFlag) so I get an exception.

```
qDebug() << jObject.GetParseError();
```

returns 6 which is (kParseErrorObjectMissCommaOrCurlyBracket).But my json object is valid.

I could not find a solution but interfering the library but I do not want to. My question is how can I parse or avoid this or is there something that I am doing wrong.

There is no problem when I tried with no braces like this,

```
{ "jsonObjectName" : { "A" : "1", "B" : "\"A\":\"1\",\"B\":\"2\"" } }
```

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this with `Document::parse` and a string literal in the most recent release or trunk. Could you try to make a small code sample that fails, that I could just copy/paste to reproduce?

Comment: I am sorry there was a problem with my file reading. Now is working fine thank you.